# Selecting latest entry ordered by group, adding a user defined column for the latest one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have two SQL tables:

```
Employees
ID     Created                 RecordID     Status
------ ----------------------- ------------ ----------
1      2020-07-29 12:38:54.070 1            1
2      2020-08-03 14:28:59.803 1            1
3      2020-08-04 13:47:49.427 2            0
```

and

```
Payments
ID     EmployeeID     Amount
------ -------------- ------------
1      1              1022        
2      1              1090        
3      1              2105        
4      2              1112        
5      2              1450        
6      2              2923        
7      3              1064
```

How do I add another (user defined) column called `Latest` to the following query, that can check if the row corresponds to the Employee `RecordID` number with the latest `Created`, and returns a string `true` or `false` value for that row? In other words, a row should be `Latest: true` if its `Created` has the latest timestamp for all rows corresponding to that `RecordID` number.

Here's my SQL so far:

```
SELECT e.ID, e.Created, e.Status, p.EmployeeID, p.Amount
FROM Employees AS e
JOIN Payments AS p 
ON e.ID = p.EmployeeID
```

Here are the expected results:

```
ID     Created                     Status     EmployeeID     Amount     Latest
------ --------------------------- ---------- -------------- ---------- ----------
1      2020-07-29 12:38:54.070     1          1              1022       false
1      2020-07-29 12:38:54.070     1          1              1090       false
1      2020-07-29 12:38:54.070     1          1              2105       false
2      2020-08-03 14:28:59.803     1          2              1112       true
2      2020-08-03 14:28:59.803     1          2              1450       true
2      2020-08-03 14:28:59.803     1          2              2923       true
3      2020-08-04 13:47:49.427     0          3              1064       true
```

Thanks!

Comment: Two Employees can have the same `RecordID`

Comment: I'm confused about desired results. Is the "latest record" the highest RecordID in the employees table? The highest ID in the payments table? How do you know a payment was latest just because of the ID? (Transactions can be _committed_ out of order, for example.) Do you expect 6 rows, 2 rows, 1 row, something else? Please show us what results you expect, it's much easier to figure out than reverse engineering a word problem. Also SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type, the best you'll get is either bit (`0`/`1`/`null`) or words (literally the strings `'true'`/`'false'`).

Comment: How to identify latest record ? And its relation to payment table as you are only joining with employee id ?

Comment: Could you please add expected result as well with some more explaination.

Comment: The logic is not clear enough. Please add the expected result for your example.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated the question. @AaronBertrand

Comment: I still don't understand what makes a row `true` vs. `false`. You say `the row corresponds to the RecordID with the latest Created by Employee` but you have tagged the first three rows as false even though they have _the same_ RecordID as the next three rows, which were created by a different EmployeeID and have a different RecordID than the last row, which is also true. Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AaronBertrand a row is true if: Its `Created` has the latest timestamp for all rows corresponding to that `RecordID`. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT e.ID, e.Created, e.Status, p.EmployeeID, p.Amount,
    Latest = CASE DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.RecordID ORDER BY e.Created DESC) 
      WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
  FROM dbo.Employees AS e
  JOIN dbo.Payments AS p 
  ON e.ID = p.EmployeeID
)
SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Latest payment is the Employee `RecordID` with the latest `Created`. See edited question

Comment: This is why relying on word problems and assuming we're all familiar with your data model can make questions hard to answer. That is not "latest payment" that is "latest created employee." If you've changed entity names to try to dumb down the problem, it had the opposite effect.